# Need to multiply values in same row within excel file using input

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import csv

file_reader = csv.DictReader(open('FILENAME.CSV','r'))

for row in file_reader:

    print(row)

animal_input=input("What kind of animal?")

print("To buy all those animals costs:"PRICE*QUANTITY)
```

I need to be able to type the animal's name in `input()`, so the PRICE X QUANTITY will appear. However, this data table is inside the excel file, so I do not know how to reference from the `input()` to the "ANIMAL" column in the Excel File, nor do I know how to include Price and Quantity as well.

```
ANIMAL         PRICE   QUANTITY
ANTEATER         5         4
BEAR             3         4
CAT              3         4
DOG              2         3
ECHIDNA          2         2
```

Comment: You can read the entire csv as a dataframe and then use lookup to pick up the values you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict perhaps, and compute the results on reading.

```
import csv
import StringIO

csv_pretend_file = """ANIMAL,PRICE,QUANTITY
ANTEATER,5,4
BEAR,3,4
CAT,3,4
DOG,2,3
ECHIDNA,2,2"""

animals = {}

for row in csv.DictReader(StringIO(csv_pretend_file)):
    animals[row['ANIMAL']] = int(row['PRICE']) * int(row['QUANTITY'])


animal_input=input("What kind of animal?")
print("To buy all those animals costs: {}".format(animals[animal_input]))
```

Demo:

```
What kind of animal?ANTEATER


To buy all those animals costs: 20
```